# Exibição do menu lateral em uma Form

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

Tenho um form que exibe um menu lateral de acordo com esse código:

```
procedure TFMainMenu.FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
   Y: Integer);
begin
PanelMenu.Visible := (Mouse.CursorPos.X < FMainMenu.Width -(0.95*FMainMenu.Width) )
end;
```

O problema é que quando o form não está "full screen", esse menu lateral não aparece usando essa função. Alguma sugestão?

PS: O MainMenu é um formulário **Pai** e o formulário que é criado quando clico no botão do menu dele herda o formulário **Pai**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Problema é que você está usando a posição absoluta do mouse em `Mouse.CursorPos.X` ao invés de utilizar o parâmetro `X` com a posição relativa do mesmo. Portanto:

```
procedure TFMainMenu.FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
   Y: Integer);
begin
PanelMenu.Visible := (X < FMainMenu.Width -(0.95*FMainMenu.Width) )
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Minha sugestão é manter o projeto somente em fullscreen e tirar os botões de maximizar a tela, também pode fazer uma procedure para quando a tela for diminuida.

Comment: O problema é que o ideal é que a tela não fique full screen 100% do tempo